# I am using Scrapy to crawl data, but the server block my IP

Tags: selenium, networking, ip, scrapy

[image]

As the picture showed, I am using scrapy to crawl the data from **Server**, but The **Server** seem to block my ip, I am curious about that the **Server** block the ip of **my mac** or the ip of **router**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**it is the router's public IP which is blocked.**

In this scenario there are two networks.

One, the public internet - Where the server (hosting the website you crawl) is connected.

Two, your private home network - Where your Mac is connected.

Your router acts as a gateway from your private home network to the internet and thus helps your Mac talk to the Server.

To act as a "Gateway" the router will have two IP addresses. One private IP address for your home network and one public IP address. The public IP address is what is visible to the server. In the Server's viewpoint the public IP address is from where the crawl requests are made.

Hence **it is the router's public IP which is blocked.**

Also please respect a website's Terms of Service and crawl responsibly.

If you don't want to get banned try the following settings in the settings.py:

1. Limit [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests)
2. Set [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)

Reference : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: actually, I am crawling data by my school network, so you mean the server ban all of the ip that under my school router? is that correct??

Comment: Assuming your school has only one gateway and one public address, yes. Everyone in your school may get banned. But schools typically have many gateways and ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It will get the address of provided by your Internet provider, so your public IP. could check this post: [Get proxy ip address scrapy using to crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364630/get-proxy-ip-address-scrapy-using-to-crawl])

Comment: there is only one seem like a ip address. http://127.0.0.1:56750/hub/session       do u know whats that mean?

Comment: well, I was not precise with stating you will find your ip in the headers.. It's still the public IP as stated that should be the one used for scraping (so that if you get banned, you will be fine if you e.g. go to a cafe next door). The address that you show in your comments is your localhost with the selenium hub, which was used as a proxy (if proxy is used it shows in response.headers). So perhaps only your selenium "got banned", and your router's IP address is fine to use with this server.